# pgfplots - How to use figures with commas when comma separator is defined empty?

Tags: pgfplots

As the MWE shows, the separator for every 1000th count was defined empty (for the lack of a better term) since the first column represents the year.

So running the MWE does not work, since pgfplots does not parse numbers with `,` as 1000 separators/indicators. I'm a bit confused and would like to reassure if this is the right thought: should every figure in the input file then just consist of numbers and no other character whatsoever?

**data01.csv**

```
2006;50,000
2007;100,000
```

**data02.csv**

```
2006;100000
2007;150000
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
pgfplots,
amsmath
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
lmodern,
textcomp
}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\def\parsedate#1-#2!{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1+1/12*(1#2-101)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
    %height=7cm,
        %width=14cm,
    %axis lines*=left,
        ymin=0,
        xmin=2006,
        xlabel={abc},
        ylabel={def},
        enlargelimits=upper,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
        legend style={at={(0.6,1.2)}},
        stack plots=y,
        %legend columns=4,
        legend cell align=left,
        every axis x label/.style={
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                anchor=west,
                },
        every axis y label/.style={
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                anchor=south,
                },
]
\addplot [mark=*, mark indices={1,6}] table [col sep=semicolon] {data01.csv}
node[pos=0, above right=5pt, fill=white]{257,000}
node[pos=1, anchor=south, yshift=3pt, fill=white]{244,862};
\addlegendentry{Text 1}
\addplot [mark=x, mark indices={1,7}] table [col sep=semicolon] {data02.csv}
node[pos=0, above right=5pt, fill=white]{2.000}
node[pos=1, above right=5pt, fill=white]{1.998};
\addlegendentry{Text 2}
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only be applying this 1000's separator definition to the printing of your tick marks on the x axis.  For this use `x tick label style` or equivalently `xticklabel style`.   In any case this is not affecting reading from the input file.  For that, you can tell `pgf` to ignore commas via an `ignore chars` option:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
pgfplots,
amsmath
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
lmodern,
textcomp
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\def\parsedate#1-#2!{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1+1/12*(1#2-101)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
        ymin=10,
        xmin=2006,
        xlabel={abc},
        ylabel={def},
        enlargelimits=upper,
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},
        legend style={at={(0.6,1.2)}},
        stack plots=y,
        legend cell align=left,
        every axis x label/.style={
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                anchor=west,
                },
        every axis y label/.style={
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                anchor=south,
                },
]
\addplot [mark=*, mark indices={1,6}] table [col sep=semicolon,ignore chars={\,}] {data01.csv}
node[pos=0, above right=5pt, fill=white]{257,000}
node[pos=1, anchor=south, yshift=3pt, fill=white]{244,862};
\addlegendentry{Text 1}
\addplot [mark=x, mark indices={1,7}] table [col sep=semicolon] {data02.csv}
node[pos=0, above right=5pt, fill=white]{2.000}
node[pos=1, above right=5pt, fill=white]{1.998};
\addlegendentry{Text 2}
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I have added a `compat` setting to `pgfplots`, and replaced `ymin=0` by `ymin=10`, both to suppress warnings.

Comment: Thanks. So how can I apply the 1000's separator definition only to the printin gof the tick marks?

Comment: By putting it in the `tick label style` as I did above.

Comment: Actually, that wasn't the "best" solution, but helped me immensely anyhow. With this I searched around a bit more in the manual and I then found on p. 276 ff in the manual: `xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},`. So thanks!

Comment: Indeed to just set the style along the x-axis, which I agree is most appropriate here, you should use `x tick label style` (with spaces) rather than `tick label style`.

Comment: Based upon my reading of p. 277, I'd say they are the same. If you know more, could you please share? And maybe source it? :)

Comment: You are right, p. 277 shows that both `x tick label style` and `xticklabel style` are defined and are the same.

Comment: Please provide your comment as a full answer so I can mark it as the solution.